# Spring Security - Random salt + Hash + Custom UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-security

Last question on this from me hopefully. So far I've implemented my own custom UserDetails and UserDetailsService classes so that I can pass the random salt that was used at the time of password creation. Hash of password is SHA512. However upon trying to login I always get user/pw combination incorrect and I can't seem to figure out why.

I store the hash and salt in the db as blobs, any ideas on where the issue lies?

```
Security-applicationContext.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <sec:http auto-config='true' access-denied-page="/access-denied.html">
        <!-- NO RESTRICTIONS -->        
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/*.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"  /> 
        <!-- RESTRICTED PAGES -->
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*.html" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/athlete/*.html" access="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_STAFF" />

        <sec:form-login login-page="/login.html"
                    login-processing-url="/loginProcess"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1"
                    default-target-url="/member" />
        <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
    </sec:http>

    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="PATH.TO.CustomUserDetailsService"/>
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="512"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"> 
                <sec:salt-source user-property="salt"/> 
            </sec:password-encoder>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

CustomUserDetails.java

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private int userID;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String salt;

    public CustomUserDetails() {
    }

    public CustomUserDetails(int userID, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities, String username, String password, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean enabled, String salt) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
        this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
        this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return accountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return accountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    public void setAccountNonExpired(boolean accountNonExpired) {
        this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
    }

    public void setAccountNonLocked(boolean accountNonLocked) {
        this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public void setCredentialsNonExpired(boolean credentialsNonExpired) {
        this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setSalt(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private User_dao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDao(User_dao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        MyUser myUser = new MyUser();
        myUser.setUsername(username);
        try {
            userDao.getUserByUsername(myUser);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        if (myUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found", username);
        } else {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(myUser.getUserRole().getAuthority()));

            int userID = myUser.getUserID();
            boolean accountNonExpired = true;
            boolean accountNonLocked = myUser.isNonLocked();
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
            boolean enabled = myUser.isEnabled();
            String password = "";
            String salt = "";

            password = new String(myUser.getHash);
            salt = new String(myUser.getSalt());
            CustomUserDetails user = new CustomUserDetails(userID, authList, username, password, accountNonExpired, accountNonLocked, credentialsNonExpired, enabled, salt);
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Password Creation

```
public byte[] generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    byte[] salt = new byte[20];
    random.nextBytes(salt);
    return salt;
}

public byte[] generateHash(byte[] salt, String pass) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    digest.update(salt);
    byte[] hash = digest.digest(pass.getBytes());
    return hash;
}
```

Call in method:

```
byte[] salt = generateSalt();
byte[] hash = generateHash(salt, password);
Which I then store in the db.
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same original problem, which was never answered, so in the hopes that this might save someone time in the future:

Spring-Security adds braces by default prior to comparing digests. I missed that and spun my wheels for hours (d'oh).

**Make sure you store (or generate) your salt values enclosed with curly braces** (i.e., when Spring says '{salt}' they sincerely mean 'open curly brace + your salt value + close curly brace'.

I suppose this was obvious to most people, but I didn't notice it until I finally debugged down into it.

Answer (score -3):

It's worth pointing out, I think, that storing the salt used for each user's password in a salt column in the database (although common) present a vulnerability.  The reason for salting in the first place is to prevent dictionary attacks against a compromised database.  If an attacker had access to your database and no salt were used, they could apply common hash algorithms to every word in a standard dictionary to create new dictionaries of hashes.  When they find a match for one of those words in the database, they consult the mappings in their own dictionary to find the original unhashed word that produces that hash when the algorithm is applied.  And voila!  The attacker has a password.

Now... if you apply a salt and the salt is different for each user, you throw a massive monkey wrench into that attack plan.  BUT... if you STORE the salt for each user in the database (and make it obvious by naming the column "salt") you're not actually interfering all that much with this attack plan.

The most secure approach I know of is this.

1. Have no salt column in your user table.
2. Implement a getSalt() method on your UserDetails class.  Have it return some other user attribute that was set when the user registered and will NEVER change.  e.g. join date.  Concatenate that with a string literal/constant that's hard-coded in your UserDetails class.

In this manner, salts will be unique to every user.  What value was used as a salt will not be evident from looking at the database.  And even if an attacker guessed what was used for part of the salt, he/she would ALSO need access to your source code to know the REST of the salt.  This means your database AND application code would BOTH need to be compromised before you end up with a real issue on your hands.

Assuming you understand the merits of everything I just said, there's also a considerable advantage here in that what I just said is actually easier to implement than what you're already doing.  Love it when the right thing turns out to be the easier thing!

Comment: Well if they had the source code wouldn't they know how the salt was generated? They'd have the string literal from the code and they'd know the field in the db it was. If it was something easy like join date or user id that wouldn't be hard to crack, let alone just look up on a site.

Regardless, even if I did implement it as you mentioned, that still doesn't solve my problem of SpringSecurity not verifying the password correctly. Is it the variable type byte[] that's the issue?

Comment: @Kent "The reason for salting in the first place is to prevent dictionary attacks against a compromised database." This is wrong, salts are for protecting against **precomputed attacks**, not dictionary attacks. Also it protects against shared passwords between accounts. If a password is cracked you only get access to that one account, instead of that account and everyone who used the same password as that person. You are basically advocating security through obscurity.

Comment: @Felix, you're right.  If someone CAN see source AND the database, they can figure out a salt, but that's better than storing the salt in the database, because then someone needs access to the database only to learn the SALT for a given user.  Re: your original question- sorry I failed to answer it.  Looking at it again... there's a disagreement between SS and the database about what the hashed password is.  The best way to settle this disagreement is to have the code that writes the password to the database use the passwordEncoder bean to compute the hash.

Comment: @Scott, if I was wrong about anything, it was only the "dictionary" attack label. The details are correct however. If you store the salt in a user table in a column CALLED salt, you have just informed an attacked who has already compromised your database of EXACTLY what salt was used for that user's password. Now they just need to guess from among a handful of algorithms and they can execute your "precomputed attack" that might yield the password for a single given user. When the salt source isn't obvious AND split between the database and code, that attack vector is closed.

Comment: (And I know "security by obscurity" is bad.  But that's really an admonishment not to implement "security ONLY by obscurity."  Obscuring sensitive information is ONE (of many) legitimate components in any thorough security solution.  If you doubt me, I ask you what a hashed or encrypted value is...  is it in itself not obscured information?)